# Error LicenseWebpackPlugin is not a constructor with Angular CLI

Tags: angular, build, angular-cli, production

I need help. I have a project in angular 4 with angular cli 1.4.5. When I execute "ng build" all works fine, but when I execute "ng build --prod" get an error:

```
license_webpack_plugin_1.LicenseWebpackPlugin is not a constructor
TypeError: license_webpack_plugin_1.LicenseWebpackPlugin is not a constructor
    at Object.getProdConfig (D:\Proyectos\Angular\project-name\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\webpack-configs\produ
ction.js:81:27)
    at NgCliWebpackConfig.getTargetConfig (D:\Proyectos\Angular\project-name\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\webpack
-config.js:40:42)
    at NgCliWebpackConfig.buildConfig (D:\Proyectos\Angular\project-name\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\webpack-con
fig.js:24:18)
    at Class.run (D:\Proyectos\Angular\project-name\node_modules\@angular\cli\tasks\build.js:27:92)
    at Class.run (D:\Proyectos\Angular\project-name\node_modules\@angular\cli\commands\build.js:204:26)
    at resolve (D:\Proyectos\Angular\project-name\node_modules\@angular\cli\ember-cli\lib\models\command.js:261:20)
    at Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Class.validateAndRun (D:\Proyectos\Angular\project-name\node_modules\@angular\cli\ember-cli\lib\models\command
.js:240:12)
    at Promise.resolve.then.then (D:\Proyectos\Angular\project-name\node_modules\@angular\cli\ember-cli\lib\cli\cli.j
s:140:24)
    at <anonymous>
```

I hope your help, please.

Comment: have you tried to reinstall `node_modules` by removing the whole `node_modules` folder at first?